# Autorization required after iisreset and server restart

Tags: iis, active-directory, dynamics-crm, windows-server-2012, ntlm

We have a Microsoft Dynamics CRM app on Windows Server 2012.

There is anonymous/Windows auth on server.

When we make iisreset or just restart server there is some chance to make server inaccesable with 401 error.
This behaviour is strange at minimum because on server and app level there is anonymous auth and in other cases it works perfectly.

Solutions that we tryed:

- another iisreset

  not working
- disable then enable Windows Authorization in iis settings

  strange but works

In Event Viewer we not found anything interesting.

Is there any approach to identify problem (debug/trace Window Authorization module)?
What this can be?

Comment: "We have a Microsoft Dynamics CRM app on Windows Server 2012." For Dynamic CRM, you cannot treat it like any other ASP.NET web apps due to its complexity. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and work with Microsoft support team would be a better option.

Comment: @LexLi this problem is also reproduced on our usual ASP.NET applications that are located on the same server on ports 8080 and 8081, not only on Dynamic CRM app

Comment: Then analyze IIS log files to see what exactly were the sub-status codes when the issue occurred, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Once that's clear, you can move on (each sub-status codes have different troubleshooting steps).

Comment: @LexLi There is no helpefull information in high level IIS logs.
All request denied by 401.2 (Denied by Server Configuration) and win32 code 5 (Access denied).
There is no information which module/configuration return this response.